# Calling JavaScript methods from typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently, I'm trying to use work with the online view of the document and I came across this website.https://rollmyfile.com/.

when I head towards the developer APIs https://rollapp.readme.io/v1.0/docs/rollmyfile-js-api. I find I can read any document by passing the URL. But I'm working on angular 4 which uses typescript so I did call out

so I placed the js code in my index.html

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.rollapp.com/1/js/rollmyfile.js"></script>
```

now I need to make use of this js file to pass the Url to it something this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var key = "SeCur3AP1K3y";

    var rollMyFile = new RollMyFile(key);
</script>
rollMyFile.openFileByUrl("https://www.example.com/documentation/overview.docx");
```

so, I need to make use of .openFileByUrl in my `.component.ts`

I have referred the path as well in my `.component.ts` something like this

```
///<reference path="https://api.rollapp.com/1/js/rollmyfile.js"/>
```

but still, I'm not able to create an instance of RollMyFile.

I'm getting `[ts] Cannot find name 'RollMyFile'` error.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should probably declare your RollMyFile somewhere in the components you need it `declare RollMyFile: any`. Would be better if you had typings but this should be enough to get it working.

Comment: i did it but its throwing me an error `Cannot find name 'RollMyFile'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.RollMyFile'`

Comment: Can you please add the component where you try this call to your question?

Comment: Hint: `<reference path...` doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare RollMyFile on top in order to use that function in your TS file

```
 declare const RollMyFile: any;

ngOnInit() {
 console.log("hi");
 var key = "SeCur3AP1K3y";
 var rollMyFile = new RollMyFile(key);
 console.log('rollMyFile',rollMyFile)
}
```

This console giving me error because of having wrong secret key.

Comment: Currently,  got the valid key but when I follow your steps it is throwing an error. `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '_apiHost' of undefined`

Comment: Add new keyword in from of function name..Check updated solution

Answer (score 0):

try this in your component :

```
declare RollMyFile: any;
constructor(private _script: ScriptLoaderService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this._script.load('body', 'https://api.rollapp.com/1/js/rollmyfile.js')
        .then(result => {
        });
    }
}
```

and use `RollMyFile` in your code something like this:

```
(<any>RollMyFile).somfunction();
```